# When classifying images to folders Error Comes Failed to get device properties, error code: 30 Keras

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

```
    examples
data_226000_227000.h5_286.png
D:/Icorve Project/Learn Neural Networks/Looking Straight/data_226000_227000.h5_286.png
(531, 413)
(531, 413, 3)
(180, 140, 1)
[INFO] loading network...
2020-01-07 09:24:19.310174: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:87] Failed to get device properties, error code: 30
2020-01-07 09:26:35.773432: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:87] Failed to get device properties, error code: 30
[INFO] classifying image...
examples
data_226000_227000.h5_288.png
D:/Icorve Project/Learn Neural Networks/Looking Straight/data_226000_227000.h5_288.png
(531, 413)
(531, 413, 3)
(180, 140, 1)
[INFO] loading network...
2020-01-07 09:30:36.892513: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:87] Failed to get device properties, error code: 30
2020-01-07 09:32:51.847629: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:87] Failed to get device properties, error code: 30
[INFO] classifying image...
```

When classifying images to folders Error Comes  Failed to get device properties, error code: 30 Keras
Some images are classifying correctly. What this error

Comment: These links might help: 1) https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26255#issuecomment-494870645 2) https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10161#issuecomment-470700352

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two GPU's let's say `Intel GPU` and `NVIDIA GPU`, then please choose graphic driver to `NVIDIA GPU` by opening NVIDIA control Panel.

In case if you are using only one driver then please ***update*** `NVIDIA GPU` graphic driver.